# Unable to GET("http://localhost:4321") in R

Tags: r, web-services

I managed to start R server using `servr::httd()` but I am unable to run `GET()`

> To stop the server, run `servr::daemon_stop("4329265464")` or restart your R session
>
> Serving the directory /Users/ at http://127.0.0.1:4321

I am able to call yahoo using `GET()` but nothing for `r` and `t`, not even a failed status. Can someone please help me?

```
library(httr)

s <- GET("http://www.yahoo.com")
http_status(s)


r <- GET("http://127.0.0.1:4321")
http_status(r)


t <- GET("http://localhost:4321")
http_status(t)
```

Comment: do you have any error?

Comment: no errors, the cursor didnt even appear...

s <- GET("http://www.yahoo.com")
> http_status(s)
$category
[1] "Success"

$reason
[1] "OK"

$message
[1] "Success: (200) OK"

> 
> t <- GET("http://localhost:4321")

Comment: my localhost website http://localhost:4321 is running, it is showing me some text

Comment: Hi, I read somewhere that GET() only takes in HTTPS. Hence have put in SSL to GET(https://localhost:4321) via https://github.com/dakshshah96/local-cert-generator/. Also, following the url i have used app.js as my server in order to include the SSL. Now I am getting this error in my browser=> Cannot GET /  and this error in R => http_status(r)
$category
[1] "Client error"

$reason
[1] "Not Found"

$message
[1] "Client error: (404) Not Found"

Comment: `GET` is not limited to HTTPS connection and firefox, chrome and even command-line cURL get to that service fine (eventually). If you're looking to have a local web server to practice web scraping or scrape local HTML files, might I suggest [`devd`](https://github.com/cortesi/devd) as an alternative. It has a dev-only [R package](https://github.com/hrbrmstr/devd) as well.